# opening a new terminal in the /tmp folder exits the new terminal immediately

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line

when I type this command `open -a Terminal .` while I am on the `/tmp` folder, a terminal appears and exits immediately. Before the new terminal gets disappeared, I see this message:

```
Last login: Wed Aug  2 15:15:32 on ttys006
/tmp ; exit;
```

It happens only when I am on `/tmp`, the `open -a Terminal .` command works for any other location.

Any idea, what's going on? My machine is like this (mac osx sierra):

```
Darwin macuseer 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: For what reason are you doing this?